# Обособление оборота "как мог"

Tags: обороты-с-как

Нужна запятая: *Я отвечал ему(,) **как мог**.*

**Грамота.ру:** В значении 'по мере сил' слова ***как мог, как могли*** и т. д. не обособляются.

Возможны ли здесь варианты или решение однозначное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Хороший ответ. (Странно, что никто не оценил.)

**Примеры** (в поддержку автора)

Антонин Ладинский. В дни Каракаллы:

> Филострат составлял для Маммеи письма, так как славился  своим  хорошим стилем. Иногда он просил меня переписать для него то  или  иное  послание, найти в библиотеке нужную книгу. Но, просматривая свиток, спрашивал порой:
> — А не знаешь ли ты, друг, что сегодня готовят на поварне?
> Я **отвечал, как мог,** а он комментировал сообщение о яствах:
> — Мясо дикой козы, мелко нарубленное,  хорошо  приправленное  перцем  и
> запеченное в виноградных листьях? Это весьма вкусно.

Леонид Утесов. «Спасибо, сердце!»:

> Много писем приходило от самодеятельных коллективов и участников самодеятельности, которые сообщали, что "на смотре будут петь песни только из "Веселых ребят", просили совета, как лучше поставить концерт, составить оркестр, исполнить ту или иную песню, подобрать репертуар, просили выслать ноты, слова песен, пластинки, помочь обзавестись музыкальными инструментами. На эти письма я всегда **отвечал, как мог,** помогал, радуясь тому, что столько повсюду любителей стремятся овладеть искусством исполнения как можно профессиональнее.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Для решения подобных задач нужен **контекст.**

Формулировка, которую предлагает Грамота.ру, будет пониматься пользователями как **однозначное руководство** к действию на все случаи жизни. В этом мне видится причина общего настроя на то, что думать самостоятельно не надо,  а ответ всегда можно найти в Сети.

(1) *Он задал мне еще несколько вопросов. Я **отвечАл**, //
**как мОг** (ответить).*  Два ударения.

Это СПП с **придаточным образа действия**.

(2) *Вопросов было много. Я отвечал **как мОг** — может, и не очень удачно.* Одно ударение на обороте.

Это **цельное** выражение в значении **"по мере сил".**  Тема есть [у Розенталя.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146)